# javascript code isn't working when placed with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, onclick

I am trying to use a simple alert box using JavaScript and if works fine i want to use some jquery code in it.

This is the code in the head section of my asp.net page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function f5() {
                    alert('hi');
            }
    </script>
```

and the code that calls it is this:

```
<input type="button" id="btnGet" onclick='f5();' value="Get" />
```

but when i remove the above jquery linking it works fine Otherwise it does not shows any error.
When testing in IE8
it says:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object excepted.
```

What could be the Problem?

Comment: try including the latest version of jquery

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, but the function you're trying to run doesn't use jQuery anyway. As @3nigma suggested, it's likely something else on your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Problem after a little bit more search : got this link

[JavaScript code place in the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287599/javascript-code-place-in-the-header)

this gives proper description of problem with solution.

Anyways thanks to all for answers as it helped me to get some other information about jquery and javascript.

Answer (score 3):

it not the fault of jquery its working fine [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aX44F/1/)  maybe something else is wrong in your code

Comment: phew! Glad the jQuery library isn't broken! LOL

Answer (score 0):

Please check your jquery file is placed on appropriate location defined in the link.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is an error in the jQuery file. Try downloading the jQuery file again. The jQuery file may be corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

write this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert( $().jquery);
    </script>
```

and tell mt if its alert you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use google hosted jquery file ( http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js ) or download again.

On the other hand, your function can be implemented at the end of page, you can try.

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that your jquery.js-file dosn't contain any errors then error occurs not in the code you gave us. Your piece of code is correct as mantioned before.

Does IE8 say in what file/line error occurs? Does firefox/google chrome console say anything? It must say because js-code had not been executed.

Are you using any other javascript libraries in your project such as Mootools?

They could conflict with jquery. If yes, try to add the following code right after including jquery library.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

and use `jQuery` instead of `$` where jquery is used.

I hope it will help